# What do @, - and + do as prefixes to recipe lines in Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the GNU Makefile manual, it [mentions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell) these prefixes.

> If .ONESHELL is provided, then only the first line of the recipe will be checked for the special prefix characters (‘@’, ‘-’, and ‘+’).

What do these prefixes do, and where are they mentioned?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

They control the behaviour of make for the tagged command lines:

- `@` suppresses the normal 'echo' of the command that is executed.
- `-` means ignore the exit status of the command that is executed (normally, a non-zero exit status would stop that part of the build).
- `+` means 'execute this command under `make -n`' (or 'make -t' or 'make -q') when commands are not normally executed. See also the POSIX specification for [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) and also [§9.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html#Instead-of-Execution) of the GNU Make manual.

The `+` notation is a (POSIX-standardized) generalization of the *de facto*  (non-standardized) mechanism whereby a command line containing `${MAKE}` or `$(MAKE)` is executed under `make -n`.

(`@` is discussed in [§5.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Echoing) of the GNU Make manual; `-` is described in [§5.5](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors-in-Recipes); and [§5.7.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-the-MAKE-Variable-Works) mentions the use of `+`.)

Comment: Is it possible to combine `@` and `-` ? (don't echo, don't stop) In which order?

Comment: A quick experiment seems to indicate that the `@` and the `-` can be combined in either order and have the expected effect — the options are combined.

Answer (score 61):

`@` prevents the command line from echoing out to the console. You can do it globally with `-s` or `--keep-silent`

`-` tells make to keep going, even if the command fails for some reason. You can do it globally via the `-i` flag (or `--ignore-errors`).

`+` I was not familar with before you asked. As near as I can tell, it negates the effect of `-n`, `-t`, and `-q`, all of which basically tell make to not actually run the commands. So a line with a `+` at the front would get run anyway.

If you read the official Gnu Make manual, they are all mentioned in [Chapter 5](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipes). In my old copy of the manual that was the chapter on "commands", but term du jour now seems to be "recipes".