# How can I get 'make uninstall' to remove empty directories as well as files?

Tags: uninstallation, automake

When I uninstall an application using `make uninstall` it leaves over some empty directories which `make install` had created, e.g. such as `/usr/share/foo/` and its subdirectories such as `/usr/share/foo/applications`, etc.

I found via Google, that automake's generated `uninstall` target does not automatically delete empty directories because it does not know if the the application *owns* the directories (e.g. it created it during `make install`), or *borrowed* it (e.g. the directory existed during `make install`).

Currently none of my make files has a definitive `uninstall` target, make implicitly seems to know which files it has to remove. How can I teach it to also remove the folders in question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution, I just had to register an `uninstall-hook` target like this, and then perform the necessary tasks, for removing the directories. In this example `${pkgdatadir}` would expand to `/usr/share/foo`. The if-then is necesseary as otherwise the `make distcheck` target would fail.

```
uninstall-hook:
    if test -d ${pkgdatadir}/applications; then rmdir ${pkgdatadir}/applications; fi
    if test -d ${pkgdatadir}; then rmdir ${pkgdatadir}; fi
```

The `uninstall-hook` rule will be called after the uninstall target has run.

Comment: It's not clear where you registered the uninstall-hook. Did you append this segment to a Makefile? Please elaborate some more...

Comment: Added to my Makefile.am file, the position does not matter, just add it somewhere at the end.

Comment: I believe these should be `$(DESTDIR)$(pkgdatadir)`, etc.  I suspect this solution will not work when DESTDIR is non-empty.

Answer (score 5):

The above is excessively verbose.  Here's a shorter version:

Register an uninstall-hook target, and then perform the necessary tasks, for removing the directories. In this example ${pkgdatadir} would expand to /usr/share/foo. The minus sign in front of rmdir tells make to ignore the return code (so that if the directory isn't empty, make won't fail) Note that the minus sign can be used in front of any make target command.

```
uninstall-hook:
    -rmdir ${pkgdatadir}/applications
    -rmdir ${pkgdatadir}
```

The `uninstall-hook` rule will be called after the uninstall target has run.

Here's more about the minus sign: [What do @, - and + do as prefixes to recipe lines in Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Does this go in `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am`?

Comment: It goes in `Makefile.am` !