# What is the meaning of @! in a make file?

Tags: makefile

What is the meaning of `@!` in the following code from a make file? I check the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) but find no answer:

```
check:
    @echo "checking for tabs in shell scripts"
    @! git grep -F '    ' -- '*.sh'
```

Comment: This is just a guess, but I'd say the ! is an alias for the `shell` function (invoking the `git` command in a subshell) and the @ is suppressing the output from that command.

Comment: this looks like it can be solved with a simple google search, but it can't. i am giving a +1 for at least checking the `make` manual.

Comment: The Make part is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` inverts the return value of the command. [`@` suppresses the echoing of the command itself](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing). Make gives you an error if any of the commands returns a non-zero value. Using `!` just inverts the situation. The reason `!` is not listed in the manual is that it's bash.

Comment: The usage of `!` is documented in [Bash Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines).

Comment: @JingguoYao of course I meant it's not documented in make because it's bash