# What does the syntax @: mean in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I see the following rule in an ancient `GNUMakefile`.

```
always:            
    @:
```

What does it mean?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3477292 -- the ':' does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '@' tells make to run the command but not echo the results.

The ':' is a shell command that does nothing.

This target appears to be a target that simply does nothing and does not tell you about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to tell make to execute the command but not to echo it to the terminal.