# What is the variable $(MAKE) in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, build

I am currently learning how to write makefiles. I've got the following makefile (which was automatically generated for a C-project that should run on an ARM chip), and I'm trying to understand it:

```
    RM := rm -rf

    # All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
    -include sources.mk
    -include FreeRTOS/Supp_Components/subdir.mk
    -include FreeRTOS/MemMang/subdir.mk
    -...
    -include subdir.mk
    -include objects.mk

    ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
    -include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
    endif
    ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
    -include $(C_DEPS)
    endif
    endif

    -include ../makefile.defs

    # Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

    # All Target
    all: FreeRTOS_T02.elf

    # Tool invocations
    FreeRTOS_T02.elf: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
        @echo 'Building target: $@'
        @echo 'Invoking: MCU GCC Linker'
        arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -T LinkerScript.ld -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -o "FreeRTOS_T02.elf" @"objects.list" $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
        @echo ' '
        $(MAKE) --no-print-directory post-build

    # Other Targets
    clean:
        -$(RM) *
        -@echo ' '

    post-build:
        -@echo 'Generating binary and Printing size information:'
        arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "FreeRTOS_T02.elf" "FreeRTOS_T02.bin"
        arm-none-eabi-size "FreeRTOS_T02.elf"
        -@echo ' '

    .PHONY: all clean dependents
    .SECONDARY: post-build

    -include ../makefile.targets
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around the line `$(MAKE) --no-print-directory post-build` in the rule for making the `.elf` file.

I cannot find a definition for the variable `$(MAKE)`, so I assume that it is something built-in. What is this line actually doing?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a recursive invocation of `make` itself, forwarding the `-t`, `-n` and `-q` options. This makes sense: you want the nested `make` invocations to run with these options as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got another (not really related) question. Why do the `@echo` commands in post-build have a `-` character preceding? The `@echo` commands in the rule for making the executable doesn't have it.

Comment: @K.Mulier, `-` is used to ignore errors if a command failed (with non-zero exit status). see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make) for details. However, I don't really understand why it is there in `@echo`.

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable):

> The value of this variable is the file name with which make was invoked

It is useful in cases where to make some target you'd have to call *its* makefile, but you are doing some sort of dry run with `-t` (`--touch`), `-n` (`--just-print`), or `-q` (`--question`) flags. That behaviour would propagate recursively if `($MAKE)` is used.

Comment: What exactly is " the file name with which make was invoked " ?

Comment: Remainder of paragraph from the doc: *If this file name was /bin/make, then the recipe executed is ‘cd subdir && /bin/make’. If you use a special version of make to run the top-level makefile, the same special version will be executed for recursive invocations.*

Comment: So, if I start the GNU make program by double clicking the file `C:\Apps\SysGCC\arm-eabi\bin\make.exe`, then the $(MAKE) variable will expand to the String `"C:\Apps\SysGCC\arm-eabi\bin\make.exe"`?

Comment: Okay, 'double clicking' is somewhat too simplistic because that implies no options given to it. But you get the point ;-)

Comment: > *if I start the GNU make program by double clicking the file*

Yes, it should be. You could try writing a simple makefile that does `echo $(MAKE)` or something like that to be sure.

Comment: That's a great idea!
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: thanks for including the doc link

Answer (score 3):

Please don't get confused with the earlier answers saying recursive call.
`$MAKE` is the default variable which gets replaced with "make".

And in your scenario, `$MAKE` is used in commands part (recipe) of makefile. It means whenever there is a change in dependency, make executes the command `make --no-print-directory post-build` in ***whichever directory you are on***.

For example if I have a case where in

```
test.o: test.c
      cd /root/
      $(MAKE) all
```

It says, if there is a change in `test.c`, execute `make all` in `/root` directory.

Comment: This example demonstrates a very common mistake.  Each line of a make recipe is handed to the shell **independently**.  Thus, if you want to execute something in the directory `/root` then the recipe should be something like `cd /root/ && $(MAKE) all`.  As written, the line `cd /root/` will cd into `/root` and exit.  Then `$(MAKE) all` is executed in the current directory not `/root/`. This is covered in GNU Make docs.

Comment: Agreed :) Newbie then

Answer (score 3):

### Meaning of the variable `MAKE` in a Makefile

> What is the variable $(MAKE) in a makefile?

See the make manual (run `man make` locally), section 5.7.1: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable.

Let me emphasize the part where it says: "**Recursive make commands should always use the variable `MAKE`, not the explicit command name `make`.**" "Recursive" here simply means you are calling `make` inside of a makefile. So, when you call the outer Makefile with `make`, it in turn calls make again via the `MAKE` special variable rather than via `make` directly. See the manual below:

> ### 5.7.1 How the `MAKE` Variable Works
>
> Recursive make commands should always use the variable `MAKE`, not the explicit command name `make`, as shown here:
>
> ```
> subsystem:
>         cd subdir && $(MAKE)
> ```
>
> The value of this variable is the file name with which make was invoked. If this file name was `/bin/make`, then the recipe executed is `cd subdir && /bin/make`. If you use a special version of make to run the top-level makefile, the same special version will be executed for recursive invocations.
>
> As a special feature, using the variable `MAKE` in the recipe of a rule alters the effects of the `-t` (`--touch`), `-n` (`--just-print`), or `-q` (`--question`) option. Using the `MAKE` variable has the same effect as using a `+` character at the beginning of the recipe line. See Instead of Executing the Recipes. This special feature is only enabled if the `MAKE` variable appears directly in the recipe: it does not apply if the `MAKE` variable is referenced through expansion of another variable. In the latter case you must use the `+` token to get these special effects.