# Why use exec in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Is the `exec` keyword required in a Makefile?

```
build-cache: clean-cache                                    
    @exec ./scripts/copy_packages.sh
    ./scripts/build_makefile.sh
    docker build -t common/cache ./cache
```

I just noticed that some lines use exec and others do not.

Comment: Is it GNU's `make`?

Answer (score 6):

No (`exec` is not a keyword in `make`); you're misparsing the line:

```
@exec ./scripts/copy_packages.sh
```

The `@` means "do not echo this line" when executing the commands in this 'recipe'.  The `exec` means that the shell that `make` starts to run the line replaces itself with the script `./scripts/copy_packages.sh`.

See also [What do `@`, `-` and `+` do as prefixes to recipe lines in `make`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/)