# makefile stand alone @ symbol and dir keyword

Tags: makefile, gnu, symbols

I was wondering is anyone knows what the stand alone @ symbol and the 'dir' command in my makefile does here (second & third line) :

```
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $? -o $@
```

I understand what $@ is however @ by itself is not listed in the GNU handbook (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) and all my searches talk about the $@.

Furthermore, in the third line, I understand that mkdir -p creates nested directories but I was hoping if someone can please elaborate on $(dir $@) specifically the "dir" part.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should remove the c++, symbols and symbol tag as this question is entirely `GNU make` centric.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do @, - and + do as prefixes to recipe lines in Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make)

Comment: If it wasn't for the part with the `dir` keyword, I would second that duplicate flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `@` starts a recipe line, the command itself isn't echoed.

`$(dir $@)` expands to the directory part of the target `$@`. In this case that is `$(BUILD)/rest/path/to/` if the target is `$(BUILD)/rest/path/to/target.o`.

From [GNU make manual, 5.2 Recipe Echoing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing):

> ## 5.2 Recipe Echoing
>
> Normally 'make' prints each line of the recipe before it is executed.
>   We call this "echoing" because it gives the appearance that you are
>   typing the lines yourself.
>
> When a line starts with '@', the echoing of that line is
>   suppressed. The '@' is discarded before the line is passed to the
>   shell.  Typically you would use this for a command whose only effect
>   is to print something, such as an 'echo' command to indicate progress
>   through the makefile:
>
> ```
>  @echo About to make distribution files
> ```

and from the [same, 8.3 Functions for File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions)

> ## 8.3 Functions for File Names
>
> Several of the built-in expansion functions relate specifically to
>   taking apart file names or lists of file names.
>
> Each of the following functions performs a specific transformation
>   on a file name.  The argument of the function is regarded as a series
>   of file names, separated by whitespace.  (Leading and trailing
>   whitespace is ignored.)  Each file name in the series is transformed
>   in the same way and the results are concatenated with single spaces
>   between them.
>
> '$(dir NAMES...)'
>        Extracts the directory-part of each file name in NAMES.  The
>        directory-part of the file name is everything up through (and
>        including) the last slash in it.  If the file name contains no
>        slash, the directory part is the string './'.  For example,
>
> ```
>       $(dir src/foo.c hacks)
> ```
>
> produces the result 'src/ ./'.

Comment: Just for some new readers, the construct `$(dir $@)` can be replaced with `$(@D)`. (Same goes for the file name in the target as `$(@F)`.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a silencer. When `@` is the first character of a command, the said command is executed without being printed in stdout beforehand.

See [Makefile documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing) for additional info:

> Normally make prints each line of the recipe before it is executed. We call this echoing because it gives the appearance that you are typing the lines yourself.
>
> When a line starts with ‘@’, the echoing of that line is suppressed. The ‘@’ is discarded before the line is passed to the shell. Typically you would use this for a command whose only effect is to print something, such as an echo command to indicate progress through the makefile:
>
> ```
> @echo About to make distribution files
> ```
>
> When make is given the flag ‘-n’ or ‘--just-print’ it only echoes most recipes, without executing them. See Summary of Options. In this case even the recipe lines starting with ‘@’ are printed. This flag is useful for finding out which recipes make thinks are necessary without actually doing them.
>
> The ‘-s’ or ‘--silent’ flag to make prevents all echoing, as if all recipes started with ‘@’. A rule in the makefile for the special target .SILENT without prerequisites has the same effect (see Special Built-in Target Names). .SILENT is essentially obsolete since ‘@’ is more flexible.