# What does @+SKIP_ENV=true mean in this Makefile?

Tags: variables, makefile, command, gnu-make, symbols

I'm tinkering with [this](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjxray) project where Step 6 requires me to run a command like `make db-prepare-artix7`. This command corresponds to [this](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjxray/blob/5349556bc2c230801d6df0cf11bccb9cfd171639/Makefile#L141) section of the Makefile. I am confused by the [@+SKIP_ENV=true](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjxray/blob/5349556bc2c230801d6df0cf11bccb9cfd171639/Makefile#L147) in the recipe. What is `@+SKIP_ENV` here, and what does it do? Couldn't find anywhere referring to `SKIP_ENV`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do @, - and + do as prefixes to recipe lines in Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make)

Comment: `SKIP_ENV` is the name of a shell variable. The variable is set to `true` in the context of the following shell command `source...`.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I found that answer before posting. It helped me learn of @ and +, but doesn't tell me what `SKIP_ENV=true` is doing, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet But I can't find where `SKIP_ENV` is defined. Interestingly, making `SKIP_ENV=false` does not seem to alter the outcome, whereas deleting `SKIP_ENV=true` entirely (so the line starts with `source...`) would lead to an `AssertionError` about a missing file, but the following `update_parts.py` runs correctly.

Comment: @NoobAdmin As `SKIP_ENV` is defined in the context of sourcing another shell script, and only for this purpose, you should probably look at this other script if you really want to understand what it is used for.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Okay found it [here](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjxray/blob/5349556bc2c230801d6df0cf11bccb9cfd171639/utils/create_environment.py#L56). It seems that `main()` will `return` as long as `SKIP_ENV` is not void, which might be why `SKIP_ENV=false` and `SKIP_ENV=true` behaves the same. In fact, I found out that even `SKIP_ENV=blah` works! I guess the authors just wrote `true` to help with reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining every part:

- The `@` means the command will not be echoed by Make during recipe execution
- The `+` means the command will be executed even during dry runs: `make --dry-run ...`
- The `SKIP_ENV=true` is sh(ell) syntax for setting the environment variable `SKIP_ENV` to the string `true` for the duration of the command that follows

  - In your case the `source ...` command
  - The effect of `SKIP_ENV` depends on the command - dig deeper to find out

Comment: Thanks! I found `SKIP_ENV` [here](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjxray/blob/5349556bc2c230801d6df0cf11bccb9cfd171639/utils/create_environment.py#L56). In this case the variable's value is irrelevant as long as it's set to something. Anyway thanks for answering, now I can keep on researching the project!